# Пробел в строке при вызове программы

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт, который вызывает с++ программку с несколькими параметрами, грубо такая:

```
cust='Ivanov I.I.'
.../prog -cust $cust
```

В этом случае `echo cust` выводит `Ivanov I.I.`, а в программе только то, что до пробела.

Что можно сделать?

Comment: добавить в строку двойные кавычки напрямую пробовали? `cust='\"Ivanov I.I.\"'` как-то так, я не помню нужен / или нет.

Comment: 1) `cust='"Ivanov I.I."'` 2) `prog -cust \"$cust\"` P.S. А каким местом тут тег `C++`?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

оболочка вначале осуществляет подстановку переменных, а уж затем исполняет команду.

поэтому строка

```
.../prog -cust $cust
```

сначала превратится в

```
.../prog -cust Ivanov I.I.
```

а уже затем она будет интерпретирована: будет сделан [*fork*](https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fork&category=2), и дочернему процессу (`.../prog`) будут переданы три параметра:

```
-cust
Ivanov
I.I.
```

ваша же программа, вероятно, ожидает лишь два параметра (точнее, вероятно, опцию и её значение).

---

чтобы избежать разбиения строки `Ivanov I.I.` на два параметра, можно использовать двойные кавычки:

```
.../prog -cust "$cust"
```

тогда после подстановки значения перменной `$cust` будет получена строка

```
.../prog -cust "Ivanov I.I."
```

и дочернему процессу будет передано только два параметра:

```
-cust
Ivanov I.I.
```

---

p.s. на самом деле параметров будет в обоих случаях передано на один больше, но я опустил этот момент для простоты изложения.

---

**простая иллюстрация**

```
s='a b'

f() {
  echo $#
}

f $s
f "$s"
```

в качестве вызываемой «программы» здесь выступает функция `f()`, которая выводит в *stdout* количество переданных параметров.

данный скрипт, будучи интерпретирован любой *posix*-совместимой оболочкой, вернёт два числа:

```
2
1
```

т.е. во втором случае строка `a b` будет передана целиком как один параметр.

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало)

Comment: если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка» слева от ответа).